# How can I get destination to copy file in Google Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm looking for the way how to upgrade security level of developing of Google Script projects.
Now I'm trying to make file back up. I want to have back up files in expected directory on the script owner Google drive only.

I made a script

```js
function copyScriptToBackUp (){
  const scriptId = ScriptApp.getScriptId();
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(scriptId);  
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");  
  const name = file.getName();
  const title = `${date} ${name}`;  
  let dest;
  if (file){
    try {
      dest = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('ScriptBackUps')[0];     
      } catch(err) {
      dest = DriveApp.createFolder('ScriptBackUps');
      }
  } 
  file.makeCopy(title, dest); 
}
```

it works but not correct: new files are coming to the root directory of editor drive and variable `dest` returns `null` value. How can I save back up in the `dest` directory on script owner drive?
Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I've had the same problem in the past and I used the Drive API to change the parents of the script files.  Note: changing the parents is the same as moving the file.

Comment: @Cooper What about setOwner(getOwner() )? But no idea how to move it to the directory

Comment: It's a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/63152055).

Comment: @Cooper you know some more effective way to backup files?

Comment: That loop I gave you is part of a project backup which also backs up the source code from a team/shared drive to my local drive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a loop that makes a copy files and looks for files that are of type "MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT"  and makes a slight deter in the loop for them moving them by changing the parents using Drive API.

```
  for(var i=0;i<aObj.idA.length;i++){
    var fObj=findFilesInTeamDriveFolder1(getGlobal('rtiTeamDriveFldrId'),aObj.idA[i]);
    for(var j=0;j<fObj.filesA.length;j++){
      aObj.filesA.push(fObj.filesA[i]);
      var file=DriveApp.getFileById(fObj.filesA[j].id);
      var copyName=file.getName();
      var res=file.makeCopy(copyName,subFldr);
      if (file.getMimeType() == MimeType.GOOGLE_APPS_SCRIPT) {
        Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": subFldr.getId()}]}, res.getId(), null, {"supportsTeamDrives":true}); // Added
      }
      html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />%s - FileName: <strong>%s</strong> FileId: <strong>%s</strong>',k++,file.getName(),file.getId());
    }
  }
```